# Volley memory leak on HEAD requests

Tags: android, out-of-memory, head, android-volley

Regarding `Volley library` for Android:

If I make a lot of HEAD requests, my device will quickly run ouf of memory. 
The reason why this happens seems to be that `Volley` allocates memory based on Content-Length even in HEAD requests, for example at row 212 of [BasicNetwork.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java).

> new PoolingByteArrayOutputStream(mPool, (int) entity.getContentLength());

What I'm doing:

```
RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
for(link : various_links_of_mp3_files){
    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Method.HEAD, URL, null);
    mRequestQueue.add(req)
```

Is anyone experiencing the same issue? Is it a bug or just my fault?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: how do you handle the answers of your requests? I try to use Method.HEAD as well, but I always get an error (specifically com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.EOFException), even if the URL is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by myself, it's a library bug.
If someone has the same problem, you have to add the following additional IF statment at line 110 of [BasicNetwork.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java)

```
// If request method is HEAD, there is no need to allocate
// memory
if (request.getMethod() == Request.Method.HEAD) {
     responseContents = new byte[0];
}
// Some responses such as 204s do not have content. We must
// check.
else if (httpResponse.getEntity() != null) {
    responseContents = entityToBytes(httpResponse.getEntity());
} else {
    // Add 0 byte response as a way of honestly representing a
    // no-content request.
    responseContents = new byte[0];
}
```

Doing so, Volley doesn't allocate anymore Content-Length memory.
Thank you anyway if anyone has tried to help me with no result.